# CSS - Equal width images with variable heights

Tags: html, css

I'd like to display an arbitrary number of images in rows where each row contains exactly 3 images of fixed widths. However I would like the height of the rows to be the same height as the tallest image in row, similar to the layout of the blocks in the image below.

[image]

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
.ItemContainer{
    width: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.ItemContainer li{
    float: left;
}

.ItemContainer li img{
    width: 180px;
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 0;
}
```

However it seems like the browser is attempting to fill white space instead of display them in rows, is there a way to achieve this layout using only CSS?

Comment: after every 3rd image put a clearfix div

Comment: can you also share your html structure ?

Comment: can you use the html/css/js embedded tool and share the sturcture?

Comment: Take a look at flexbox

Comment: For better browser compatibility just wrap every 3 images with a block level element, example in my answer.

Comment: Use [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i assume your struture is ul>li>img .

- `Flex` will help:
  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 570px;/* width given to force wrapping */
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  background: gray;
}

li {
  display: block;/* remove bullet */
  width: 180px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;/* fill whole width */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/250" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

- Or you may deal with the `float` way *(CSS used very closed to flex. block formatting context has to be minded. compatible from IE7)*

dealing with float : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

about BFC https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 570px;/* width given to force wrapping */
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  background: gray;
  overflow:hidden; /* triggers bfc to deal with float children */
}

li {
  display: block;/* remove bullet */
  float:left;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;/* fill whole width */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/250" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I wouldn't pick `flex` as the solution for this (pretty simple) scenario, since it is still not fully supported (IE... i know... but still...)

Comment: @RonenCypis well, then float just does fine, i'll copy/paste the snippet into a float version

Answer (score 0):

Wrap every 3 images inside a containing block element (`div.row` in the example) like so:

```css
.row {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
.row img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" class="aa" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" class="bb" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/120/" class="cc" />
</div>
<div class="row">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/30/" class="dd" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/210/" class="ee" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/140/" class="ff" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
This is something i made during my project if u want to change the height then made several blocks of different height and float them to the left but be careful about the width, etc...

```
.part{
  background:;
  height:auto;
  width:%;
  float:right;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.block{
background-color:#ffd700;
float:left;
width: 200px;
height:300px;
border: 2px black;
padding-right:25px;
margin-top:3px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:35px;
color:black;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or use a wrapper div

```css
.wrapper {
  clear: left;
}
.ItemContainer{
  width: 200px;
}

.ItemContainer li{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.ItemContainer li img{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="ItemContainer">
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x150"></li>
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x100"></li>
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="ItemContainer">
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x150"></li>
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x100"></li>
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, there is no reason to wrap the single element `ul` with the `.wrapper` div. Other than that, this is exactly my answer :-)

Comment: oh well, it's my personal style :) And apparently I could have refreshed the screen to check for answers before clicking 'post my answer'.

Comment: With no regards to any personal style, redundant nesting makes my eyes twitch ;-)

Comment: Your `li`'s are already wrapped with the containing `ul`, so the `div` is totally useless there...